# Video Player App for MKV?

Tags: video, media-player

Having trouble finding an app that will smoothly play .MKV (matroska video) files. (For those unfamiliar with the format, MKV is commonly used for HD video.)

The popular QQ, Mobo, Mvideo, and MX players result in choppy, un-synced play. These apps do the same on my 2.1 device.
I am using Samsung Galaxy Ace with Android 2.3 and these QQ, Mobo, Mvideo, and MX players are not able to play .mkv file smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried switching between Hardware/Software Modes in MX/Mobo Player ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HD Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.truong531developer.player) and [Real Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.real.RealPlayer) sound promising to play mkv videos smoothly. But, if video quality is overloading your hardware capabilities, no software can help playing that HD video smoothly. However, you can do one thing: Install Hot Reboot from Play Store and run it once before video playback. It'd reduce load on system.

If you're unable to play that video on your device, I'd recommend you to use Handbrake to rip that video for your device.

Answer (score 7):

[VLC media player beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) for android was just released today. You can take a look at it. I am not sure if it works fine on Ace though

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem might be with the phone. The galaxy ace is at the lower end of the scale hardware wise so I imagine it can't handle HD files.

Answer (score 0):

This article of [Best Android Video Players for Android Phone](http://video-player-software.blogspot.com/2012/09/best-android-player-for-android-phone.html) will be helpful, I think.

Good luck. Personally, I prefer [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) and [MX player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) (also allows background playback)

Answer (score 0):

If you find your mobile stutters with HD videos.... This is because of the limitations of your hardware... You can convert the videos before watching them.... 
The player of my choice is MX player... It is perfect.... For playing files not supported on your mobile, you can go to the list option and add the extension manually after which you will be able to play....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try RealPlayer or VLC for Android Beta. But I am not sure whether it supports it or not. For detailed information, you can view this article: [Top 6 Video Player Apps for Android Mobile Device in 2012](http://samsung-center.blogspot.com/2012/11/top-6-video-player-apps-for-android.html)

Anyway, I have downloaded the QQ player on my HTC One X, and found that it works well on my phone. So if the video player still can't play the mkv video, maybe you can convert the mkv video to mp4 or 3gp format. Then, watch it on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) works fine with `.mkv` files.

You just need to make sure you turn on all the H/W settings and select H/W+ when playing an .mkv file.

Go to

- Tools>Settings>Decoder
- tick all the boxes in the Hardware Decoder list.

That worked for me.